# Получение результа работы grep в скрипте

Tags: bash, grep

Пытаюсь сохранить результат работы grep, но в итоге имею 0, хотя во входных данных точно есть подстрока. Проверял из командной строки, все работает идеально, а вот в скрипте не хочет. Задача: сформировать файл `$OUT_FILE` со всеми строками из файла `$COLS_SRC`, которые встречаются в файле `$SRC` хотя бы один раз.

```
#!/bin/bash 
OUT_FILE=./cols_for_drop.txt
SRC=./source.sql
COLS_SRC=./columns.txt 

while read line
     do
      nums=0
      nums=`grep -ci "${line}" "${SRC}"`
      echo "nums = "$nums
      if [[ "${nums}" -eq 0 ]]
        then
          echo $line >> $OUT_FILE
        else 
          echo "false"
      fi
    done < $COLS_SRC
```

При выполнении скрипта nums всегда равен "0". Благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `"${SRC}"` а значение этой переменной откуда берется? И что в переменной `$COLS_SRC`?

Comment: Изменил код примера, теперь должно быть понятно

Comment: А подключиться к базе откуда взят `./source.sql` не вариант?

Comment: Данный файл генерится неизвестными мне процедурами и результат экспортируется через web-страничку. На самом деле это приложение Oracle APEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К счастью, удалось победить самостоятельно.
Достаточно было удалить символы перевода каретки из исходного файла вот таким образом:

```
cat $COLS_SRC  | tr -s '\r\n' '\n' > $COLS_CLEAR
```

В итоге рабочий вариант скрипта выглядит примерно так:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT_FILE=./cols_for_drop.txt
SRC=./source.sql
COLS_SRC=./columns.txt
COLS_CLEAR=./columns_clear.txt

cat $COLS_SRC  | tr -s '\r\n' '\n' > $COLS_CLEAR

while read line
  do
  nums=0
  nums=$(cat $APEX_SRC | grep -ci $line)
  if [[ "${nums}" -eq 0 ]]
    then
      echo $line >> $OUT_FILE
    else 
      echo false
  fi
done < $COLS_CLEAR
```

Comment: *Useless use of cat* Да и по первому же пункту `man dos2unix; man unix2dos`

Answer (score 1):

Позвольте немного подправить Ваш код:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT_FILE=./cols_for_drop.txt
SRC=./source.sql
COLS_SRC=./columns.txt
COLS_CLEAR=./columns_clear.txt

sed 's/\r//g' $COLS_SRC > $COLS_CLEAR # это если вы не хотите менять исходник
# sed -i 's/\r//g' $COLS_SRC # и тогда можно юзать исходник

while read -r line
  do
  if ! grep -q "$line" $SRC
    then
      echo "$line" >> $OUT_FILE
      # tee -a $OUT_FILE <<<"$line" # Если сделать так вместо echo, то вы будете видеть в процессе выполнения какие строки ушли в результирующий файл
    else
      echo false 
  fi
done < $COLS_CLEAR
```

> Блок else можно опустить поскольку функциональной нагрузки он никакой не несет. Посему условие в цикле можно записать гораздо короче.

```
while read -r line; do
   grep -q "$line" $SRC || echo "$line" >> $OUT_FILE
done < $COLS_CLEAR
```

> А вообще, если хорошо подумать, то всю конструкцию можно записать в одну строку

`grep -vx "$(sed 's/\r//g' $COLS_SRC)" $SRC > $OUT_FILE`

> Опять-таки, если Вы хотите видеть что добавляется в файл можно сделать так:

`tee $OUT_FILE < <(grep -vx "$(sed 's/\r//g' $COLS_SRC)" $SRC)`

Comment: Благодарю за дополнение. Действительно, все ваши замечания имеют смысл. Bash -- штука интереcная и иногда мозголомная :)